# JSON deserialization to object

Tags: apex, json

I am sending object data `({FirstName=Test, Id=0030m00000WyQ6ZAAV}, {FirstName=Arya, Id=0030m00000YF2SBAA1})` to the Apex method like below

```java
@AuraEnabled
public static List<MockResponse> updateContacts(Object data,String objName) {
    // {FirstName=Lalith, Id=0030m00000WyQ6ZAAV}, {FirstName=Arya, Id=0030m00000YF2SBAA1}
    List<Contact> contactsForUpdate = (List<Contact>) JSON.deserialize(
            JSON.serialize(data),
            List<Contact>.class
    );
    system.debug('contactsForUpdate'+contactsForUpdate);
    try {
        Database.SaveResult[] srList = Database.update(contactsForUpdate, false);
        List<MockResponse> errorResult = new List<MockResponse>();
        Map<String,String> errorData = new Map<String,String>();
        errorData.put('Id','Message');
        for(Integer i=0;i<srList.size();i++){
            if (srList.get(i).isSuccess()){
                srList.get(i).getId();
                system.debug('I came here !!');

            }else if (!srList.get(i).isSuccess()){
                // DML operation failed
                Database.Error error = srList.get(i).getErrors().get(0);
                String failedDML = error.getMessage();
                contactsForUpdate.get(i);
                system.debug('Failed ID'+contactsForUpdate.get(i).Id);
                MockResponse mr = new MockResponse();
                mr.Id = String.valueOf(contactsForUpdate.get(i).Id);
                mr.errorMessage = failedDML;
                errorResult.add(mr);
            }
        }
        System.debug('errorData'+errorResult);
        return errorResult;

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        system.debug('exception occ'+e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Right now, I am deserializling the object like below

```java
List<Contact> contactsForUpdate = (List<Contact>) JSON.deserialize(
    JSON.serialize(data),List<Contact>.class
);
```

but,I want to do it for any object data passed like contact,Account etc. Please help me out here I am passing object name as other parameter but unable to deserialize.

Comment: Did you try `List<SObject>.class`?

Comment: tried below 


1.
 SObject customObject = (SObject)JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(data), Sobject.class);
 
 System.debug('customObject '+ customObject);
 
ERROR :  System.JSONException: Json Deserialization failed on token 'null' and has left off in the middle of parsing a row. Will go to end of row to begin parsing the next row

Comment: 2.  List<Object> results = (List<Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(JSON.serialize(data));
            system.debug('results'+results);
   

response : results({FirstName=Lalith30, Id=0030m00000WyQ6ZAAV})

Comment: I said `List<SObject>` not `List<Object>`.

Comment: yeah tried with sobject one also below is the code
 List<SObject> results = (List<SObject>)JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(data), List<SObject>.class);
  System.debug('results'+results);
   
Error:  System.JSONException: Nested object for polymorphic foreign key must have an attributes field before any other fields.

Comment: OK, that makes sense since the SObjects have no attributes property specifying the type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aura/LWC supports direct serialization/deserialization of objects. Just use:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static MockResponse updateRecords(sObject[] records) {
```

As for the client side, make sure there's an attributes property:

```
[ { "attributes": { "type": "Contact" }, "FirstName": "John", ... }, ... ]
```

Coincidentally, if you want to pass in the type, you could use Type.forName, but the syntax is a bit annoying to get just right sometimes.

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<MockResponse> updateContacts(Object data,String objName) {
    // {{attributes={type=Contact}, FirstName=Lalith, Id=0030m00000WyQ6ZAAV}, {{attributes={type=Contact}, FirstName=Arya, Id=0030m00000YF2SBAA1}
    List<sObject> contactsForUpdate = (List<sObject>) JSON.deserialize(
            JSON.serialize(data),
            Type.forName('List<'+objName+'>')
    );
```

But seriously, there's no need to serialize/deserialize data yourself, just let the platform do what it was designed to do.